# Spring XD configuration step by step for multi node

Tags: spring

I'm trying to configure Spring XD in distributed mode. I am not able to find any document which can define the basic steps like how many minimum nodes should be created, in which node should I install Redis... Please provide a document if possible for the set up

Comment: Start with http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I've went through the document, but the steps mentioned are high level. Is there any document where I can get the basic information?